# 1 $templateCache, 2 modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-templatecache

In an angular app, I have a module that I want to use within another.

module A defines listController and the list.html file that goes along with that controller

All html files are put into $templateCache. In the module A scripts, I see

```
$templateCache.put("app/components/defaults/list.html","<div ... etc
```

module B wants to use the listController and html from module A. So, module A is defined as a dependency.

Module B has a route defined as so

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
        "name": "mystate",
        "url": "/mystate",
        "templateUrl": "/app/components/defaults/list.html",
        "controller": "ListController",
        "controllerAs": "vm",
        "service": "SomeService"
    });
```

when accessing this route, I see that I get

```
GET https://myhost/app/components/default/list.html 404 (Not Found)
```

what am I missing ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the leading `/` in `templateUrl` that doesn't exist in the `$templatCache` path.

The strings need to match an `===` comparison ,  the same way any object property name would

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I did find the problem though :( *blushes*

Answer (score 0):

soooo, at the risk of publicly ridiculing myself ...

The solution is to actually, really include module A as a dependency. Not module C ...

Sorry for the waste of time and bandwidth.